# White page appear after save button - i have logs

Tags: php, smarty

I have a problem I have a CMS panel based on PHP smarty 
A few days ago on hosting we changed PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.2 
Everything seemed to work. 
But I noticed today that the "save" function in the "add page" section
does not work, after clicking "save" a white page appears

please help

Checked logs

```
/home/srw_strona/strona.pl/lib/classes/Session.class.php on line 29
[17-Jul-2019 13:55:37 Europe/Warsaw] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function valid_text(), 3 passed in /home/srw_strona/strona.pl/admin/action/content.module.php on line 485 and at least 4 expected in /home/srw_strona/strona.pl/lib/MVC.function.php:460
Stack trace:
#0 /home/srw_strona/strona.pl/admin/action/content.module.php(485): valid_text('text', 'Jakas tresc<br ...', Object(Form))
#1 /home/srw_strona/strona.pl/admin/index.php(109): contentMultiActionController->form_action()
#2 /home/srw_strona/strona.pl/admin/index.php(162): MVC_Controller->Process()
#3 {main}
  thrown in /home/srw_strona/strona.pl/lib/MVC.function.php on line 460
```

Comment: It's right there in the error: `Too few arguments to function valid_text()`

Comment: Is this the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57073365/php-smarty-on-php-7-2 if so combining them as a single question will bring the logs together with the code and make it easier to answer.